# Function uniquely determined by its values at integer arguments

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, riemann-zeta-function, interpolation

A smooth enough, slow growing real-valued function $f(x)$, is uniquely determined by its values at integer arguments. I don't remember the name of the theorem and the conditions for this to be true. Can someone refresh my memory and provide the link / reference to this statement?

I worked on this topic a while back, and came up with the following formula, valid for a large class of even functions:

$$f(t) = \frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi}\cdot \Big[\frac{f(0)}{t} +\phi'(t)\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{f(k)}{\phi(t)-\phi(k)}
\Big]$$
where (say) $\phi(t)=t^2$. I posted it on MO a while back, and even proved the formula. I remember the proof was quite simple, but I can't remember any of it. There's quite a bit of details in my earlier question from years ago, on MO, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376081/infinite-partial-fraction-expansions-to-compute-fractional-iterations-and-recurr). It was a question about interpolation.

I am again interested in this topic, and I applied the above formula to the real part of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(t+i\sigma)$, and it works. It works at least for $0<t<20$ and $\sigma=0.8$. This surprises me a bit since that function does not satisfy the conditions required to guarantee convergence to the right solution (conditions that I found myself but they could be more strict than actually needed).

If you want to answer a question a bit more challenging than my initial question, you can answer whether my formula applies or not to the real part of the Riemann zeta function, even for large values of $t$ and different $\sigma$'s. But at this point I am only interested in a reference to the theorem in question.

**Update**

I wrote an article unrelated to this topic (it's about fuzzy spatial regression as a machine learning technique), and not yet completed. However Exercise 2 in section 5 deals with the problem described here. You can download the article [here](https://ln5.sync.com/dl/cdf596ab0/8qn76awt-gyjjafdr-evqgq52d-vnda48k2).
[image]
Figure: Dirichlet eta function (real part, bottom) and interpolation error (top)

Comment: Possibly the vast topic of the distribution of zeries of entire functions of exponential type contains what you are looking for. A standard monograph is by B. Ja. Levin.

Comment: The Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ itself is uniquely determined by it's values at the positive even integers (or negative odd integers).

Comment: @Steven that's a very loose statement as there are tons of entire functions (or if you prefer meromorphic with a pole at $1$) that have the same values as RZ on any sequence of numbers without an accumulation point; one has to qualify the statement by some other specific properties of RZ

Comment: You probably right that I was being a bit sloppy. I thought I read it somewhere on the Internet a while back. I searched for the source more recently because I was interested in learning more about it, but I couldn't seem to find the source.

Comment: @Steven what is definitely true is that the values of RZ at positive even integers determine the truth of falsity of RH and for that matter so do the values of the positive odd integers from $3$ on (using the well known Riesz and Hardy Littlewood criteria respectively)

Comment: @Conrad My interest was motivated by the discovery that the coefficients $a(n)$ of $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$ and $F(s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(n)}{n^s}$ can be determined from the values of $F(s)$ at the positive even integers when $F(s)$ converges for $\Re(s)\ge 2$. See the answer I posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160465 to a question on Math StackExchange.

Comment: @Conrad I guess what I should have said is any function $F(s)$ corresponding to a Dirichlet series $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(n)}{n^s}$ is completely and uniquely determined by it's values at the even positive integers when the Dirichlet series converges for $\Re(s)\ge 2$.

Comment: In my last comment above, I meant uniquely with respect to other Dirichlet series.

Comment: @Steven but that is trivial since any two Dirichlet series that converge on some half-plane $\sigma \ge a$ cannot coincide at infinitely many points without being equal

Comment: @Conrad I suspected it was once I realized what I really should have said, but what I find interesting is the fact that the values of $a(n)$ can be determined from the values of $F(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty$ at the even positive integers which the author of the paper at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.09818.pdf refers to as the Dirichlet inversion theorem.

Comment: @Conrad But the paper was just the tip of the iceberg. The answer I linked above reveals the broader picture. The paper focuses on complex analytic representations of $a(n)$ whereas my answer focuses on real analytic representations of $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$ and $f'(x)$ and shows the complex analytic representations of $a(n)$ are related to the real analytic representations of $f'(x)$.

Comment: Why do you think that paper is correct? Among other things it claims a proof of RH

Comment: @Conrad I don't think the paper is entirely correct, but it provided the seed for my derivations which led to the answer I posted on Math StackExchange which I believe to be correct. I don't have a rigorous proof of my results, but I believe I provided enough information to enable others to explore their correctness.

Comment: In these topics handwaving easily leads to mistakes so I would first have a riguros proof before claiming any result

Comment: @Conrad It was a bit more than handwaving, My verification was based on comparison of Maclaurin series coefficients. Granted I only compared a finite number of coefficients, but I provided enough information for others to explore these coefficients. Perhaps someone smarter than myself could derive a rigorous proof. But these results are related to analytic representations that I've been studying for many years since I posted my original question on Math StackExchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1980231, and consequently my confidence in these results is pretty high at this point.